# How do I add Google's Workbox to an Angular project?

Tags: angular, workbox

I'm trying to utilize Google's Workbox in my project but there are no current tutorials or guides on the steps to get workbox working with a new angular project. Does anyone have any insight or resources on how this sort of thing is done since angular uses typescript instead of straight js? For example, does the workbox wizard work with an angular project or do I need to do anything special?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many ways to use Workbox in your Angular project

If you use webpack, you could generate easily a service worker with the `workbox-webpack-plugin`, all the stuff on how to use it is detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin).
You can use the `GenerateSW` to generate a full working service worker, runtime caching, etc. There is also the `InjectManifest` plugin to create a precache manifest and inject it inside your own service worker.

Btw if you'd rather write your own than use the plugins, you are still able to write your service worker with straight js in your Angular project, and use the Angular `ServiceWorkerModule` to register it to your app with the `register()` function (this should be done inside the `imports` array of your main Angular module).
You also need to import the workbox library into your service worker with `importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.6.2/workbox-sw.js');`

I have never used the workbox wizard so I cannot tell you more about it but the above should do the trick.

Comment: So is that why you must use npm start? since it's webpack? Because I've tried to get it working using ng-serve but the service worker either doesn't register or it's redundant, or gives back a bad http request.

Comment: Did you follow this guide https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started ?
It says that `ng-serve` does not work with service workers (see the `Serving with http-server` part).
Webpack is not mandatory but it provides you simple ways to manage service workers.